# It breaks after inputting a number and I don't know why

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ProgramPractice4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please give me a number. Decimals are allowed.");
            double posx = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine("Please give me another number. Decimals are allowed.");
            double posy = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine("Please give me one more number. Decimals are allowed.");
            double posz = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine(posx + posy + posz);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't input anything on Notepad++'s Console, but when I used an online compiler, it broke after inputing a decimal number. Even after making sure decimal numbers allowed. What went wrong?

Comment: Decimals are NOT allowed, you're converting to an int32 which is a whole number.

Comment: What "doesn't work" about your code? Other than the previously mentioned decimal issue, your posted code looks fine to me.

Comment: What went wrong?  You missed the error message "Unhandled exception. System.FormatException" ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow decimals I would suggest using `Decimal.Parse` to convert the input to numbers. Or even better, use [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-7.0). It might be useful to put that inside a helper method to loop until the user actually inputs a number.

```
public static decimal GetNumberFromConsole(string question){
  Console.WriteLine(question);
  while(!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var result){
    Console.WriteLine("Not a decimal number, try again");
  }
  return result;
}
```